# Agile social media analysis and implementation

Tags: social-media

Are there any books/platforms for social media campaign planning and implementation that define a completely agile approach to engaging audiences on platforms such as Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter, etc?

---

**UPDATE:** Posted a bounty on the question since the current answer is really not about agile approaches to social media campaign planning and implementation.

---

**UPDATE 2:**  The question is asking for an agile social media approach, or a social media platform that has agile social media approach baked-in.

If the question was about an agile approach to software development, SCRUM would be the most likely answer of an "agile approach", since it's my understanding that roughly 70% percent of agile software developers say they practice some form of SCRUM. Pivotal Tracker might be one of many "agile software planning" platforms suggested; as a generalization Pivotal Tracker might be called a software project management platform.

On the flip-side, suggesting just a "social media platform" might be the equivalent of suggesting a "project management platform"; meaning the suggestion lack a suggestion of both an "agile social media platform" and "agile social media approach", and the problem is that if you haven't suggested an agile social media approach to try on this social media platform, then you haven't provided an answer to the question.

---

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend any specific book (though I've linked to one I'm about to read) but I would advise you to research books and blogs which focus on [Barack Obama's](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/11/10/business/media/10carr.html) 2008 US election campaign and [Alex Salmond's](http://sluggerotoole.com/2011/04/07/snp-steps-out-into-the-post-obama-election-era/) 2011 Scottish election victory.

Obama pionerred the art of the distributed (in terms of personnel) [social media campaign](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/11/10/business/media/10carr.html). He used volunteers on the ground with Apps to gain information and micro-donations from voters in conjunction with software on the back end to tie the information together and modify the message/campaign based on the feedback (in an Agile fashion). The achievement was impressive.

The guys who wrote the software used by his campaign went on to design [Nation Builder](http://nationbuilder.com/) which was used by the Scottish National Party to run social media during their 2011 campaign.

It may also be worth reading this analysis of [Anonymous's failed attack on the Vatican](http://www.securitynewsdaily.com/1567-anonymous-vatican-cyberattack.html) since they organise and recruit entirely through social media and work in a distributed and agile way.

There is also an interesting new book called [Share, Retweet, Repeat: Get Your Message Read and Spread](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735204616) by John Hlinko which may be of interest to you.

**UPDATE:** My answer really does relate to Agile Social Marketing, it's really about the political campaigns that pioneered it. If you go and read/research what they did and what they learned you'll find out a lot more about it than in any marketing book.

Anyway here are a few books about the subject:-

- [Michelle Accardi-Peterson's Agile Marketing: The Flaws of So Many Virtues](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/143023315X) Recommended by [Wayne Kernochan](http://waynekernochanblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/michelle-accardi-petersons-agile.html)
- [Feed from John Cass' Blog about Agile Marketing](http://pr.typepad.com/pr_communications/agile-marketing/)
- [Data-Driven Marketing: The 15 Metrics Everyone in Marketing Should Know](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470504544)
- [Online Marketing Inside Out](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980576822)

Comment: +1 @toomanyairmiles: Interesting, though guess after reflecting on your answer for a little bit, the main issue I see with your answer is that there is no direct reference to "agile social media analysis and implementation" within it; meaning even if I was to research the campaigns you suggested, it is unclear if those campaigns used any form of agile social media analysis and implementation. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @blundersI suppose it depends on your definition of agile. In that they changed the campaign, message calendars, events and general planning based on analysis of feedback via social media then you could say the campaigns were organsied into sprints in an agile manner.

Comment: +1 @toomanyairmiles: Yes, I would agree that agile is about taking the smallest meaningful action, learning from it, and adapting. Noticed your update to include Hlinko's book, though it's not clear why it's relevant beyond just being another book on social media. Guess I'm just surprised that given how dynamic social media is that agile campaigns are not common. One example, appears to oddly be IBM, and though the [article is not as how to as I'd like](http://www.fastcompany.com/1779375/move-over-social-media-here-comes-social-business).

Comment: @blunders Nation Builder have a good deal of information on their site about campaigns with their software - that might be worth spending some time on too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like RavenTools might be up your alley.  They have probably the most comprehensive suite out there and it integrates with Google Analytics.

http://raventools.com/social-media-tools/

Comment: _@bikedorkseattle: I've reviewed the product description page that you've linked to and see no mention of how it enables an agile approach any more than any other social media account, content, and reporting suite. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: @blunders i'm not trying to be rude here but why don't use just try it out and see if it provides you with a workflow that you consider "agile".  I always thought when it came to social the most agile approach is to let your visitors do the work for you.

Comment: +1 _@bikedorkseattle: Yes, I know you're trying to help, and if it's not clear, I'm not trying to be rude either, and +1 the comment since it's helpful that you're responding; though your answer, as I've attempted to explain in the "update 2" my question, does not answer my question. Again, thanks for the effort, which I value, but getting an topic answer is important as well.